# Rows count and assigning each row to a label

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, vbscript

A little help over here please, i'm stuck over here.
 1. I'm trying to count table rows.
 2. In this table "Policy Type" is the name. which I'm going to assign to the link label in the left corner in "Current Policies"(i'll do this through loop.i-e. At the begging there'll be no link label for each name of single row a link label will be generated which text would be "Policy Type".)
 3. After then by clicking on Link Label the description would be appear in "Current Policy Details".

Here is the design from which i explained all of this.below the design is my coding what I'm trying to do.

Design.
Sorry I can't post Image my reputation is below 10. Take a guess from the sketch below.

|""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""|
| .-Current Policies------------------------||----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| | Linklabel1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||-- Current Policy Details ----------------------------------------------------|
| |Linklabel2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
| |Linklabel3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
| |Linklabel4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
| |Linklabel5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
| |Linklabel6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
| |Linklabel7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
| |Linklabel8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
| |Linklabel9,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,||,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,|
|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**|

Code.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient  
Public Class New_Policy  
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=CILENTEYEZ-PC\CILENTEYEZ;Initial Catalog=Keeper;Integrated Security=True")  
Dim cmd As SqlCommand  
Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter  
Dim myDataSet As DataSet  
Dim dr As SqlDataReader  
Dim dt As DataTable  

Private Sub Add_Policy_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  

    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Policy")  
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()  
    dt = cmd.ExecuteScalar()  

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then  

        Label15.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString()  
    Else  
        MsgBox("There are no rows yet.")  

    End If  


    con.Close()  

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds great... wheres the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try (u might have to play around with the if then statements i am a little rusty in vb)

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient  
Public Class New_Policy  
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=CILENTEYEZ-PC\CILENTEYEZ;Initial Catalog=Keeper;Integrated Security=True")  
Dim cmd As SqlCommand  
Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter  
Dim myDataSet As DataSet  
Dim dr As SqlDataReader  
Dim dt As DataTable  

Private Sub Add_Policy_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  

    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Policy")  
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()  
    dt = cmd.ExecuteScalar()  

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then 

     Label1.Text=dt.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()  
     Label2.Text=dt.Rows(1).Item(0).ToString() 
      If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then 
        Label3.Text=dt.Rows(2).Item(0).ToString()
      End If 
      If dt.Rows.Count > 2 Then 
        Label4.Text=dt.Rows(3).Item(0).ToString()
      End If 
      If dt.Rows.Count > 3 Then 
        Label5.Text=dt.Rows(4).Item(0).ToString()
       End If 
      If dt.Rows.Count > 4 Then 
        Label6.Text=dt.Rows(5).Item(0).ToString() 
      End If
      If dt.Rows.Count > 5 Then 
         Label7.Text=dt.Rows(6).Item(0).ToString() 
       End If

 Else  
        MsgBox("There are no rows yet.")  

    End If  


    con.Close()  

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Bro for your attention.  The messy thing here is that i tried the same method but it gives error.  
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  After then I can't do any thing.

Comment: i thnk you are missing Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) from Policy", con) da.Fill(dt) again i am rusty on vb.net

Comment: Okey i'll try it this way.